# How can I register the same keymap item for different space types?

Tags: python

I have for example:

```
bpy.utils.register_class(RENDER_OT_set_fps_increase)

    kc = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = kc.keymaps.new(name="Timeline", space_type="TIMELINE")
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new('render.set_fps_increase', 'W', 'PRESS')
```

And I want to register the same key for GRAPH_EDITOR and DOPESHEET_EDITOR.
But I couldn't find a way to do it. The only thing left to try was to create two extra classes, but I want to believe there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried repeating what you have using another space_type?

Comment: Yes, it was the first thing I've tried, but didn't work, maybe I made a mistake somewhere? I'll try again.

Comment: Made a mistake indeed, I was duplicating also the register class... perks of a noob. Thanks!